# Place vector values onto the nodes in linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, nodes, graph-theory

In main function, we have a vector lists of string values.
vector names;

after my input ~~~
Then I will have
names[0] = ~, names[1] = ~

right?
Then How would I put those vector values into nodes of which we have

```
class LinkedList 
{
  public: class Nodes {
  public:
      void ToNodeValue(const string& e) { elem = e; }
      Nodes(const string& e) { elem = e; }

  private:
        string element;
        Nodes* prev;
        Nodes* next;
 };

  private: 
    Nodes* header;
    Nodes* tail; 
};
```

And I am trying to place those list of vector values to elements
so that I can form a list with nodes in which each has its own string element value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general algorithm for the main function part of the task would be to simply use a for loop to access every value in the vector and to call an insert function on a LinkedList object.
such as

```
LinkedList myList;
for(int x = 0; x < vec.size(); x++) {
  myList.insert(vec[x]);
}
```

What the actual insert function does will depend on what the problem description requires.
If you just need to tack it onto the end, then the pseduocode would be something like

```
make new node on heap with val from parameter
set tail->next to be this newNode
set newNode->prev to be tail
set newNode->next to be NULL
set tail to be newNode
```